# Enable URL rewriting to use jsessionid on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat7, jsessionid

I'm running java application on tomcat 7.

In my specific case I need to send jsessionid within URL.
Adding `;jsessionid=0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF` to the URL doesn't work - jsessionid cookie value hasn't been set properly.

I found an information that url rewriting is disabled by default since tomcat 4.

How to enable this feature for tomcat 7?

Is there a need to set a specific rules in the server configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, it is needed to set an attribute `cookies="false"` within application's `Context` configuration.

> Set to true if you want cookies to be used for session identifier
>   communication if supported by the client (this is the default). Set to
>   false if you want to disable the use of cookies for session identifier
>   communication, and rely only on URL rewriting by the application.